# Why a request to the database is reflected through the form, but not sent through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

JQuery connected, AJAX probably works correctly, because when I change select in the console the values are correct. But the query to the database doesn't change. Checking var_dump($_POST['filter']) shows that there value from previous request.
If I wrap select in a form and send it via POST using submit button, the requests are sent.
Where can there be an error here?
And how to add a condition, so that when selecting "All" the query will just be to all items "SELECT * FROM `orders`, without the condition "WHERE?

```
    <script>
    $('#filter').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "thispage.php",
            data: {
                filter: $("#filter").val()
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log($("#filter").val())

            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/database/database.php";


$item1 = $_POST['item1'];
$worker_name = $_POST['worker_name'];
$worker_company = $_POST['worker_company'];


$errors = [];

if (empty($item1)) {
    $errors['item1'] = true;
}


if (empty($errors)) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `orders`(`order_dish1`, `order_name_worker`, `order_company`) VALUES (:order1, :order_name_worker, :worker_company)";
    $params = [
        "order1" => $item1,
        "order_name_worker" => $worker_name,
        "worker_company" => $worker_company
    ];

    $dbh->prepare($sql)->execute($params);
}
$order_dishes1 = [];


?>

<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <select type="text" name="filter" id="filter">
        <option value="*">All</option>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `companies`";
        $rows = $dbh->query($sql);
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>">
              <?php echo $row['name'] ?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    
    // In this form it works
    <form action="thispage.php" method="POST">
      <select type="text" name="filter" id="filter">
          <option value="*">All</option>
          <?php
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM `companies`";
          $rows = $dbh->query($sql);
          foreach ($rows as $row) {
          ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>">
                <?php echo $row['name'] ?>
              </option>
          <?php } ?>
      </select>
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>



    <div class="orders__wrapper" id="result">
        <?php
        $company = $_POST['filter'];
        var_dump($_POST['filter']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `order_company` =  '$company'";
        $rows = $dbh->query($sql);
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
        ?>
            <div class="order-items">
                <div class="order-items__header">
                    <div class="order-items__wrapper">
                        <div class="order-items__number">
                          Order №: <?php echo $row['order_id'] ?>                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="order-items__wrapper">
                        <div class="order-items__name">
                          <?php echo $row['order_name_worker'] ?>                         </div>
                        <div class="order-items__company">
                          Company: 
                          <span>
                            <?php echo $row['order_company'] ?>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="order-items__orders">
                    <div class="orders-item orders-item-1">
                      Order №1: 
                      <span class="order1">
                        <?php echo $row['order_dish1'] ?>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
            $order_dishes1[] = $row['order_dish1'];
        }
        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        ?>

        <div class="result__all" id="result__all">
            <div class="result__all-company">
                <?php echo $row['order_company'] ?>
            </div><br>
            <div class="result__all__wrapper">
                <div class="result__all-view">
                    <div class="result__all-title">
                      Soups:
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $count_dishes1 = array_count_values($order_dishes1);
                    foreach ($count_dishes1 as $key => $val) echo '<div class="result__all-item">' . $key . ' - ' . $val . ' шт.,</div>';
                    ?>
                </div><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $content ?>
    </div>
    
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "But the query to the database doesn't change" — Do you mean that HTML shown inside `<div class="orders__wrapper" id="result">` on the page the JS is running is isn't updated with a new value?

Comment: You only send one parameter in the POST and its called `filter` See `filter: $("#filter").val()` So where are you getting these 3 parameters from? `$item1 = $_POST['item1'];
$worker_name = $_POST['worker_name'];
$worker_company = $_POST['worker_company'];`

Comment: An HTML input field MUST be placed INSIDE a `<form>` tag. Thats where the browser looks for data to send in the POST or GET when the >>FORM<< is submitted

Comment: Also remember, PHP runs on the server. It builds a page and then sends it to the browser. Then and only then (when PHP is finished running) does the browser try and run any Javascript that was sent to it

Comment: RiggsFolly, i understand that the query should change as the value of the variable $company should change.
That is, based on this variable $sql = "SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `order_company` = '$company'";
With form it works, but I don't understand why it doesn't work with AJAX

Comment: Quentin, sort of like this